# Apache/Cloudera HUE / Livy Spark Server - InterpreterError: Fail to start interpreter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera, hue, livy

I'm at a loss at this point. I'm trying to run PySpark/SparkR on Apache HUE 4.3, using Spark 2.4 + Livy Server 0.5.0. I've followed every guide I can find, but I keep running into this issue. Basically, I can run PySpark/SparkR through command line, but HUE, for some reason, does the following:

- Ignores all Spark configuration (executor memory, cores, etc) that I have set in multiple places (`spark-defaults.conf`, `livy.conf` and `livy-client.conf`)
- Successfully creates session for both PySpark and SparkR, yet when you try to do anything (even just `print(1+1)`), I get `InterpreterError: Fail to start interpreter`
- Actually works with Scala on HUE. Scala works, but PySpark and SparkR do not on HUE (presumably since Scala is java-based).

Any configuration needed I can provide. This is driving me absolutely insane.

I also cannot interact with PySpark through the REST API either, same InterpreterError. This leads me to believe it's more Livy Server based than HUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was trying to run Spark on YARN in `cluster` mode and I switched to `client` and fixed it. Must have been a missed reference/file on the cluster machines.